# Using VBA to return a field value of a given task ID in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

This is probably really simple (I am new to VBA in MS Project - Excel is more my specialty) but I am just looking to return a value of selected field in MS Project based on a given Task ID.   I (unsuccessfully) tried this:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(1).GetField(Number2)
```

...but hopefully that shows what I am trying to achieve which is finding the value of the Number2 field in the first Task of a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of the Number2 field of a particular Task by **ID**:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks(3).Number2
```

To get the value by Task **Unique ID**:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(3).Number2
```

To get the value of the Number2 field of the first **selected task**:

```
ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Number2
```

The [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method is useful if a **variable field name** is to be used:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks(3).GetField (pjTaskNumber2)
```

Comment: Note that Task ID and Task Unique ID are often different. Task ID represents the order of the tasks in the schedule whereas the Unique ID is assigned sequentially when tasks are added, regardless of position within the schedule.

Comment: Great thanks!  The ActiveSelection.Tasks... also solved another issue I was having

Answer (score 0):

You should try `ActiveProject.Tasks(1)...` to get the first task of the tasks collection:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks(object))

Comment: I tried that but because the current active task is below the first task the Tasks(1) is starting from that current active task.  I read that you need UniqueID to return a specific ID (that is not baselined from the current active task).  Or am I missing something?